# How to extract http response in node.js

Tags: node.js, http

When getting response from http get request, the response object contains many different fields. For example, if I want to extract highWaterMark value from `__writableState`, how exactly should I do that?

```
_writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var highwatermark = res._writableState.highWaterMark

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried this line of code, but still get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'highWaterMark' of undefined"

Comment: Does writableState have one or two underscores before it?
figure out which works... 
console.log(res._writableState);
vs
console.log(res.__writableState);....

whichever works, add .highWaterMark to the end :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried out the problem.  _writeableState is not the top level object in the response.